# What is the equation at the end of two functions assembly stament stands for?

Tags: functions

so I have this new topic in my class about the assembly of two functions together, and while I generally understand the basic idea, I have no idea what the equation at the end of an assembly statement stands for. so for example, if I have $g\circ f (n) = (2n -1)$ <--- here

what the equation $2n -1$ stands for?

Comment: I'm very sorry for that vary bad question, English is not my native language, witch never been a problem before,  but in mathematics, I don't know a single word. I couldn't find out how to use math symbols as well, as this is my first question.

Comment: What is your definition of "assembly of two functions"?

Comment: Right now, your question is quite unclear and I don't know that it can be readily answered.  Can you please edit your question to include some additional context?  For example, what do you mean by the "assembly" of two functions?  Could you provide a definition?  Do you, perhaps, mean the "composition" of two functions?  What are you studying, and at what level?  What book are you using (if you are using a book)?  What are the functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @G.Chiusole {1,2,3}->{a,b,c} ((1,a)(2,b)(3,c)) {a,b,c}->(!,£,$) ((a,!), (b,£), (c,$)) then the assembely of this tow would be: ((1,!),(b,£),(3,$))

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am studying "Mathematics window" (according to google translate. I'm pretty sure it is not the translation ) uni-level, the actual matching of f and g are unknown, but it is known that they are from N->N both

Comment: Probably $f\circ g$ is meant to be "composition", in English, meaning $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$.

Comment: @paulgarrett yes I know this part but what does `(2n−1)` stands for?

Comment: The composition $f\circ g$, evaluated at input $n$, produces output $2n-1$.

Comment: If I write $h(n) = 2n-1$, do you understand what that means?

Comment: @paulgarrett ok I get it now, (i think?) thanks

Comment: @XanderHenderson well we write that in our class in different syntax, but I think that means that for the input n, the function will return 2n-1

Comment: In the syntax that I have used, take $h = f\circ g$.  $f\circ g$ is just a function, albeit one *composed of* two other functions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson ok.